# Complexity Class of an Algorithm with two Inputs

Tags: complexity-theory, runtime-analysis

Consider a problem with two inputs like (P,L) and |P|=n and L is some positive integer. If my algorithm had a complexity of O(n^L), would that still be polynomial? Or is it exponential? I'm not sure if I should view L as a constant or as 'size of input', since it's not a size but just some number (as in, Knapsack for example, select items of weight <= L). At the same time, L is part of the input and not fixed.

Comment: I think you should take a look at this link. https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/909/knapsack-problem-np-complete-despite-dynamic-programming-solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're confused because you've called part of your input $n$. When we say that the running time is some function of $n$, we almost always mean that $n$ is the length of the input string.

Your algorithm runs in time $|P|^L$, where $P$ is a string contained in the input and $L$ is a number represented in the input, presumably in binary.  If $L$ is a $b$-bit number, it could be as big as $2^b$.  Writing $n$ for the length of the input, we could, for example, have $|P|=n/2$ with $L$ being an $(n/2)$-bit number.  That case gives running time $(n/2)^{2^{n/2}}$, which is a long, long way from being polynomial.

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks for your input.

Comment: if I understand this correctly, limiting L to be "some constant" would then make the input pseudopolynomial? To be more specific, I have a set of n nodes and I need to select the <= L nodes to optimize some other value, which means that brute force just tests all sets of size <= L

Comment: Yes, if $L$ is fixed (or bounded above by some constant) then $|P|^L$ is polynomial.